# How to convert HierarichalCollectionView into an XML using flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex

I'm using AdvacnedDataGrid which has the dataprovider HierarichalCollectionView, can anybody tell me how to convert an HierarichalCollectionView into XML object.

Comment: I think you're going to have to expand more on your data structure.